# Kendo UI Menu popupCollision

Tags: kendo-ui, typescript

I'm using typescript so it checks the type of the parameters.

For kendo's menu, to disable the popupCollision property you set it to false but it accepts a string so if I put in a boolean as parameter, VS gives me an error.

Here is my code

```
$('#menu').kendoMenu({
popupCollision : false});
```

VS gives me compile error that popupCollision accepts a string not a boolean.

Comment: Could you post the code that is giving you errors? It helps seeing the code. Also you might want to consider reading the how to ask a good question guide found here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the [definition file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5f8906a85905cb842e20280cbf7dee2df336eedb/kendo-ui/kendo-ui.d.ts) for kendo-ui defines that property only as a **string**.

You can just use **.toString()** to get a string out of your boolean. It's ugly but it works.

```
$('#menu').kendoMenu({ popupCollision : false.toString()});
```

If that is an error and the .d.ts file is not correct you should take it up with the people that created it.